# Получить количество без повторений в одном из столбцов

Tags: mysql, count

Имеем таблицу менеджер - входящий номер:

```
call_time | manager | aon
10:01 | user1 | 7972207
10:14 | user2 | 8581041
10:20 | user3 | 3642345
11:00 | user1 | 8089142
11:01 | user2 | 7972207
11:13 | user2 | 0297188
11:22 | user1 | 8089142
11:34 | user3 | 3642345
11:50 | user4 | 3642345
```

Нужно получить количество уникальных звонков по менеджерам. Но уникальных звонков не у каждого менеджера, а уникальных звонков вообще. Уникальный звонок в данном случае - каждый уникальный `aon`. В таблице есть временная метка, поэтому кто первый принял звонок, тому и засчитываем. Например, `3642345` уже принял `user3`, поэтому для `user4` его считать не нужно.

```
user1 2
user2 2
user3 1
user4 0
```

Comment: Нужно выбрать уникальные номера и сгрупировать их по мэнеджерам.

Comment: По какому принципу в результирующем наборе номер соотносится с менеджером? Почему номер 3642345 учтен для менеджера user3, а не для менеджера user4?

Comment: Что значит _"уникальный звонок"_? Это `aon`, которого нет у других `manager`, или это такой `aon`, который и у одного `manager` не повторяется?

Comment: @kodv потому что 3642345 уже принял user3, поэтому для user4 его считать не нужно

Comment: @i-one уникальный звонок в данном случае - каждый уникальный `aon`

Comment: Если добавим `user5 1234567` два раза, `1234567` уникальный, его нет у других, но у `user5` он два раза - это будет считаться уникальный звонок или нет?

Comment: @i-one да, номер `1234567` будет уникальным, при этом, для `user5` будет количество уникальных звонков - 1

Comment: @PavelSokolov Как определить, что этот звонок был принят впервые менеджером user3, а не менеджером user4? Есть ли в таблице какое-нибудь поле с временем приема звонка? СУБД не гарантирует выввод строг в соответствии с хронологией их создания.

Comment: @kodv да, разумеется есть временная метка. Поэтому кто первый принял, тому и count++

Comment: @PavelSokolov какая СУБД?

Comment: @kodv субд mysql

Comment: @PavelSokolov не смог я нормально перевести запрос с T-SQL на MySQL, который мне не особо знаком. Но я смотрю, вы уже нашли в ответах то, что более менее искали.

Comment: @PavelSokolov Дополните вопрос всеми этими деталями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Количество уникальных звонков с сортировкой по времени первой обработки номера:

```
SELECT `manager`, COUNT(*) AS `calls` FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT `manager`, `aon` FROM `calls` ORDER BY `call_time` ASC
    ) t1
    GROUP BY `aon`
) t2
GROUP BY `manager`
```

Comment: Кажется, это подходит. Только без группировки по `manager` во вложенном селекте.

Comment: Тому, кто первый принял.

Comment: Тогда надо сначала отсортировать звонки по времени их поступления. обновил ответ

Comment: @PavelSokolov Раз вас полностью утраивает ответ данный для MySQL, пожалуйста изначально в вопросе ставьте тег MySQL, а не просто SQL. Ибо в общем виде, для произвольной СУБД данный ответ будет не рабочим, ибо в большинстве СУБД в GROUP BY обязаны быть все колонки, которые есть в списке выборки и которым не применены агрегатные функции. Хотя в случае MySQL решение действительно красивое

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT [запрос] - уберет все повторения.

Не знаю как называется Ваша таблица но `SELECT DISTINCT aon from [название_таблицы]` вернет Вам все номера, без повторений.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT distinct(calls)  FROM calls;
```